# Scale mesh after combine mesh

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scale, mesh

First, i create 2 cube and combine into 1 mesh. I want to scale 2 cube in the center of each.

How can i do it ??

[image: 2 Cube]

My code :

```
    private MeshFilter m_MeshFilter; 
    private MeshRenderer m_MeshRenderer;
    private Mesh m_Mesh;

    private float m_Length  = 1f;
    private float m_Width   = 1f;
    private float m_Height  = 1f;
```

I Create empty gameobject and add code .

```
    private void Awake () {
        m_MeshFilter    = this.GetComponent<MeshFilter> ();
        m_MeshRenderer  = this.GetComponent<MeshRenderer> ();
        m_Mesh          = m_MeshFilter.mesh;
        m_Mesh.Clear ();

        m_Cloud = new Mesh[2, 1];
    }

    private void Start() {
        var mesh1 = DrawCube (0, 0, 0, m_Length, m_Width, m_Height);
        var mesh2 = DrawCube (1, 1, 2, m_Length, m_Width, m_Height);

// Combine 2 cube mesh
        CombineInstance[] combine = new CombineInstance[2];
        combine [0].mesh = mesh1;
        combine [0].transform = Matrix4x4.TRS (Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity, Vector3.one);
        combine [1].mesh = mesh2;
        combine [1].transform = Matrix4x4.TRS (Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity, Vector3.one);

        m_MeshFilter.mesh = new Mesh ();
        m_MeshFilter.mesh.CombineMeshes (combine);
    }
```

Draw a cube with x, y, width, height return mesh

```
    private Mesh DrawCube(int i, int x, int y, float length, float width, float height) {
        #region Mesh
        var cubeMesh = new Mesh ();
        var center = 0.5f;
        #endregion

        #region Vertices
        Vector3 p0 = new Vector3( -length * center + x, -width * center, height * center + y );
        Vector3 p1 = new Vector3( length * center + x, -width * center, height * center + y );
        Vector3 p2 = new Vector3( length * center + x, -width * center, -height * center + y );
        Vector3 p3 = new Vector3( -length * center + x, -width * center, -height * center + y );    

        Vector3 p4 = new Vector3( -length * center + x, width * center,  height * center + y );
        Vector3 p5 = new Vector3( length * center + x, width * center,  height * center + y );
        Vector3 p6 = new Vector3( length * center + x, width * center,  -height * center + y );
        Vector3 p7 = new Vector3( -length * center + x, width * center,  -height * center + y );

        Vector3[] vertices = new Vector3[]
        {
            // Bottom
            p0, p1, p2, p3,

            // Left
            p7, p4, p0, p3,

            // Front
            p4, p5, p1, p0,

            // Back
            p6, p7, p3, p2,

            // Right
            p5, p6, p2, p1,

            // Top
            p7, p6, p5, p4
        };
        #endregion

        #region Normales
        Vector3 up      = Vector3.up;
        Vector3 down    = Vector3.down;
        Vector3 front   = Vector3.forward;
        Vector3 back    = Vector3.back;
        Vector3 left    = Vector3.left;
        Vector3 right   = Vector3.right;

        Vector3[] normales = new Vector3[]
        {
            // Bottom
            down, down, down, down,

            // Left
            left, left, left, left,

            // Front
            front, front, front, front,

            // Back
            back, back, back, back,

            // Right
            right, right, right, right,

            // Top
            up, up, up, up
        };
        #endregion  

        #region UVs
        Vector2 _00 = new Vector2( 0f, 0f );
        Vector2 _10 = new Vector2( 1f, 0f );
        Vector2 _01 = new Vector2( 0f, 1f );
        Vector2 _11 = new Vector2( 1f, 1f );

        Vector2[] uvs = new Vector2[]
        {
            // Bottom
            _11, _01, _00, _10,

            // Left
            _11, _01, _00, _10,

            // Front
            _11, _01, _00, _10,

            // Back
            _11, _01, _00, _10,

            // Right
            _11, _01, _00, _10,

            // Top
            _11, _01, _00, _10,
        };
        #endregion

        #region Triangles
        int[] triangles = new int[]
        {
            // Bottom
            3, 1, 0,
            3, 2, 1,            

            // Left
            3 + 4 * 1, 1 + 4 * 1, 0 + 4 * 1,
            3 + 4 * 1, 2 + 4 * 1, 1 + 4 * 1,

            // Front
            3 + 4 * 2, 1 + 4 * 2, 0 + 4 * 2,
            3 + 4 * 2, 2 + 4 * 2, 1 + 4 * 2,

            // Back
            3 + 4 * 3, 1 + 4 * 3, 0 + 4 * 3,
            3 + 4 * 3, 2 + 4 * 3, 1 + 4 * 3,

            // Right
            3 + 4 * 4, 1 + 4 * 4, 0 + 4 * 4,
            3 + 4 * 4, 2 + 4 * 4, 1 + 4 * 4,

            // Top
            3 + 4 * 5, 1 + 4 * 5, 0 + 4 * 5,
            3 + 4 * 5, 2 + 4 * 5, 1 + 4 * 5,

        };
        #endregion

        cubeMesh.vertices = vertices;
        cubeMesh.normals = normales;
        cubeMesh.uv = uvs;
        cubeMesh.triangles = triangles;

        cubeMesh.RecalculateBounds();
        cubeMesh.Optimize();

        return cubeMesh;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah finally, My problem seem solved in simple way.

First i find center of each cube and calculate direction and then scale of it :D

It fun, anyway thank you...

```
private Vector3 CalcuateCenterMesh (Vector3[] vectors) {
    var sumVec = Vector3.zero;
    for (int i = 0; i < vectors.Length; i++) {
        sumVec += vectors [i];
    }
    return sumVec / vectors.Length;
}
```

And scale:

```
private void ScaleMesh (int index, float scale) {
        var mesh = m_MeshFilter.sharedMesh;
        var vertices = mesh.vertices;
        var min = index * 24;
        var max = (index + 1) * 24;
        for (int i = min; i < max; i++) {
            var direction = vertices[i] - m_MeshCenters[index];
            var directionNormal = direction.normalized;
            vertices [i] = directionNormal * scale + m_MeshCenters[index];
        }
        m_MeshFilter.sharedMesh.vertices = vertices;
        m_MeshFilter.sharedMesh.RecalculateBounds ();
    }
```

But if you have and better solution please give me :D

I want to create Cloud like game : "Ogre Attacks and Giant Raids! Mighty Ballista Tower Built - Kingdoms and Castles"